# Flutter esc_pos_bluetooth print image with text

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using esc_pos_bluetooth for printing in my flutter app. But now I need print image with text in a row.Because text is dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what to [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mre] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets)